# HP Notebook doesn't start with twice caps lock blink

Tags: boot, laptop, bios, battery, hp-envy

I have a HP Envy 15" noteook, 2014 series, that cannot start. The screen is completely black, and the caps lock led blinks twice.
I try to find some info about this blink error code and seems realted to BIOS.

This is what I tried without success:

- Remove all removable devices (wifi, hdd) and power on
- PowerOn with battery only and power supply only
- Remove one of two RAM modules and switch them
- Power ON with WIN+B or WIN+V with a flash drive with recovery BIOS files as suggested here: https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c02693833
- Remove and replace and also change the CMOS battery

What can I do to revive this notebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to try this procedure many times: remove battery for a few seconds, insert battery and power on.
At the end Windows could boot up and I update the BIOS using HP installer. Now it is working again.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience you should pay more attention to the RAM.

Try new RAM, may be the two RAMs are faulty, it happens sometimes.